# Height of rainfall ceiling shower

Tags: bathroom, shower, countertops

I am working on designing a bathroom with the help of a professional architect. The walls and structures are already fixed. All sizes in International System (centimetres)

[image: The "Ready Player One Bathroom"]

I had enough space to go for a "multiplayer" shower. The bathroom's height is 284cm and features a "two-players" shower box. The idea (because it's under construction) is to install hotel-like rainfall shower from the ceiling.

I have found the materials required but now I must do some considerations on the height. It's been a while I don't travel to hotels, where I saw similar showers (mostly "one-player"). The ceiling facility requires creating a countertop min. 15cm to host the pipings. Ie. the water won't run from within the cement ceiling but a pipe will come out of the wall at near 284 of height.

**Question**

Are there standards and/or **best practices** for celing/rainfall shower from countertop? What are typical heights used in such settings?

I feel that water coming from 269cm of height (105 inches) is
definitely high and will cause the water to cool too easily while dropping. And if the water doesn't come vertically at little-to-no pressure, it will go everywhere except on the head of player-1 and player-2. Reducing the quota of the ceiling by increasing the height of a countertop to reach around 2 metres will be derimental to the design. 84cm of countertop is really a punch in the belly.

Of course I am not allowed to ask a subjective question like *what should be the height of **my** bathroom*, but I am asking about *how normally hotels make these rainfall showers*, to make a better decision. The architect working for me found they can't stand this design for lack of experience, despite the rainfall idea came from a mutual brainstorming months ago.

Comment: I don't think that your use of the word "countertop" is the same as mine. What does the height of the countertop & sink have to do with the height of the shower head in the shower? Water running through plumbing won't cool _that_ much in either case, and, frankly, you wouldn't know if it did. You'd simply note that the temp in the shower isn't quite warm enough and adjust it to be warmer. Also, I find your use of "player", instead of "person", amusing. Enjoy! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hotels aren't going to have some generic standard. In fact, if my experience is any guide, they do whatever is fastest and cheapest. For them it mostly depends on:

- The height of the ceiling
- The height (length) of the shower head
- The nature of the plumbing

In your case, I'd also consider:

- The height of the users
- Proximity to door openings, etc.
- The spray pattern of the shower head

In general, a greater fall from the shower head is going to more closely create a rain-like experience--the stream will have a chance to form into individual drops.

Do recognize that the whole multi-user thing is somewhat pie-in-the-sky--much like the spa craze of the 90s it may end up being something you almost never use. Be sure that you aren't making compromises for single-user scenarios that you'll find annoying, such as having one shower head too close to a wall.

For my two cents, rainfall showers are not ideal in that you have to step out of them to lather hair, for example, wasting water and getting chilly, or you have to bend awkwardly to do so. I'd much rather have a sloped spray pattern that affords contact height adjustability while the user is fully ere... upright.